# Float property not aligning div to the top of the page correctly

Tags: html, css

If someone could help me understand why my "rightdiv" only moves past the lowest one of my "leftdiv". I have tried using "vertical-align: top" but with no effect.

(As you can probably see I am very new to HTML and CSS so please try to help me in a way I could understand to some at least extent)

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

body {
  background-color: lightgrey
}

.leftdiv {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 79%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.rightdiv {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 600px;
  float: right;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
</div>

<br/>
<div class="leftdiv">
</div>

<div class="leftdiv">
</div>

<div class="leftdiv">
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
</div>
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You are floating 3 consecutive divs to left first and then floating the rightDiv to right. If you try to understand how browsers arrange content with css, you can see that the browser is doing what you asked for, but your expectation is incorrect. You should have nested the leftDivs inside a wrapper and floated that towards left and then the rightDiv to right would have fitted nicely.
More to that, now you don't even need float, you can leverage flex or grid layouts to get this.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach. I'm somewhat partial to [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) 
Float can be used for layouts, but just isn't the most ideal way to do things. 
But yes, as Deepak said, you can just move the `rightdiv` tag up to below the first `leftdiv` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
            }

            body {
                background-color:lightgrey
            }

            .leftdiv {
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                border-radius: 15px;
                width: 79%;
                height: 200px;
                float: left;
            }

            .rightdiv {
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                border-radius: 15px;
                width: 20%;
                height: 600px;
                float: right;
                

            }

            .topbar{
                background-color: grey;
                width: 100%;
                height: 75px;
                text-align: left;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML!>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topbar">
        </div>

        <br/>
        <div class="leftdiv">
        </div>
        <div class="rightdiv"><!--placed right div near/below leftdiv-->
        </div>
        
        <div class="leftdiv">
        </div>

        <div class="leftdiv">
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Here we keep the `right div` code below **1st** `left div` so its near **1st** `left div`,

the reason is the `float: right;` property makes it **right** of the **previous div**

There are many other CSS solution But if **changing the place** of right div in **HTML** works easily *why do you want to use CSS stuffs*